# Database Design

Tags: database, database-design, geospatial

I'm trying to model nested relationships and am having a tough time getting to where I want to be.  I want to present an example that will hopefully answer some of my questions; its based on geography.

I'd like to have a single Region entity.  This region entity allows for Planets, Continents and Countries.

I would basically have a single Region called Earth.  This would be the first level of the hierarchy.  Then I would have the 7 Continents which would be nested within Region Earth.  Then I would add all the countries of the world and associate each with their outer continent.  There may be edges cases (I don't know if there are in this example, but I want there to be) where a Country belongs to more than one continent.

What I essentially want to get to is the ability to say:

Select All Countries in a Continent.  I'd like the ability to indefinitely nest too; so the next layer would be states/provinces.  So I could then say I want all provinces in North America.

I can kind of envision how the SQL would look, but I don't know how to do the multi-tier nesting:

```
Select *
From Region Outer, Region Inner
Where Outer.Name = "North America"
AND Inner.Type = "State"
```

I've come up with just a simple Region entity and then a self-referential Parent-Child entity:

```
Region {RegionID, Name, Type}
SubRegion {ParentID, ChildID}
```

I'm most interested in learning how this should be achieved.  If I'm making incorrect or poor design decisions/assumptions feel free to make your own suggestion.  I'm also not explicitly interested in the geographic stuff, I just thought it was a good example that illustrated what I am trying to accomplish.

I'm trying to do this in SQL 2008 R2 with C# and Linq.

This feels like a hierarchical network graph, so I think there should be a well understood way to do this; I just don't know it..

Comment: have you looked into SQL Server 2008 Spatial Types? Instead of having FK's mapped to ID's, you could use spatial information to work out "which countries are inside a continent".

Comment: Russia and Turkey span two continents, namely Europe and Asia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why complicate things?

Just have "country","continent","state","county","city" and "district" columns in your table.

The "country" and "continent" may seem redundant but "Moscow" is in europe and Vladivostock is in asia but both are in the Russian Federation.

Similar situations exist for Turkey, Denmark and Egypt.

Comment: Currently, though perhaps not in a couple of years time, Greenland is  part of the Denmark.

Answer (score 0):

Region mapping can be a complex problem. The primary issue is that when dealing with mapping, regions do not neatly fit into continents etc. For example, if you regard the US as a region it covers two parts of North America, and includes islands in the Pacific. many other examples come from more esoteric region mappings. One example someone mentioned to me was the Rocky Mountains which span both North America and Canada, so who does it belong to? Other region types can overlap each other rather than nest. For example, a wine region may overlap, but not completely encompass a municipal area. It may even include bits from several.

So if you are going to be dealing with regions in this sense then you will have to basically allow for multiple shapes on a map, of any shape and location, which may have any sort of relationship with other shapes.

If this is for a game then you can basically hack the model to suite yourself. I'd suggest adding some basic limitations along the lines that any given region cannot overlap another, except for it's parent which must completely contain it.

If this is for *Real* then you have the above complex issues to deal with.